# Using \newcommand in an environment

Tags: macros, environments

A command can be employed as an environment.

The macro

```
\newcommand{\rev}[2][blue]{{\color{#1}#2}}
```

simply colors its argument, for example.

Why does the corresponding environment not color the entire content?

```
\begin{document}
    black  % is correct
    \rev{in blue} \rev[red]{in red}  % correct
    black  % correct

    \begin{rev}in blue\end{rev}% only first letter is blue
    \begin{rev}[red]           % only first letter is red
        in red
    \end{rev}
    black again  % black again
\end{document}
```

As well, `\rev[\normalcolor]{text}` should work fine.

Comment: That's a wonderful example of why you should not rely on the environment `foo` calling the macro `\foo` internally. Your macro `\rev` takes a mandatory argument, and without braces it's just the first following token (in this case the first letter because spaces are discarded when looking for undelimited arguments).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to check whether the macro is used as an environment or as a normal command by checking against `\@currenvir`. The following uses this to either call `\color` (which will colour the entire contents of the environment), or `\textcolor` (which will only colour the mandatory argument).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{color}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\rev[1][blue]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \def\tmp{rev}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \ifx\tmp\@currenvir
      \expandafter\color
    \else
      \expandafter\textcolor
    \fi
    {#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    black  % is correct
    \rev{in blue} \rev[red]{in red}  % correct
    black  % correct

    \begin{rev}in blue\end{rev} % only first letter is blue
    \begin{rev}[red]            % only first letter is red
        in red%
    \end{rev}
    black again  % black again
\end{document}
```

Note that this isn't fool-proof. A usage such as `\begin{rev}abc\rev[red]{def}ghi\end{rev}` will result in `abc` being blue, and `defghi` being red.

---

A perhaps better way to check whether `rev` is used as an environment is to use LaTeX's hook mechanism to set a boolean that indicates that the current `rev` is an environment (and let the environment version set the boolean back to false). This would also work for cases such as `\begin{rev}abc\rev[red]{def}ghi\end{rev}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{color}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifrev@inenv
\ifdefined\AddToHook
  \AddToHook{env/rev/begin}{\rev@inenvtrue}
\else
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \AtBeginEnvironment{rev}{\rev@inenvtrue}
\fi
\newcommand\rev[1][blue]
  {%
    \ifrev@inenv
      \rev@inenvfalse
      \expandafter\color
    \else
      \expandafter\textcolor
    \fi
    {#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    black  % is correct
    \rev{in blue} \rev[red]{in red}  % correct
    black  % correct

    \begin{rev}in blue\end{rev} % only first letter is blue
    \begin{rev}[red]            % only first letter is red
      in red\rev[green]{test}ed%
    \end{rev}
    black again  % black again
\end{document}
```

(I made an edit which checks whether `\AddToHook` is available, and if not falls back to `etoolbox`)

Comment: I upvoted because it's definitely a smart TeXnical exercise but I cannot deny that I get some heartburn...

Answer (score 7):

```
\begin{rev}[red]           % only first letter is red
        in red
    \end{rev}
```

is more or less

```
\begingroup\rev[red]
   in red
   \relax\endgroup
```

which is equivalent to

```
\begingroup\rev[red]{i}%
   n red
   \relax\endgroup
```

By the built in rules of parsing for tex macro arguments.

---

If you want to define an environment where the body of the environment acts as a macro parameter, use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and a `b` argument. This requires the `xparse` package in older latex fromats but is built in to current releases.

Of course for the specific example of `\color` no argument is needed, just use `\color{red}` and the scope of the colour change will end at the end of the environment.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of that. So one should expect that `\newcommand{\rev}[2][blue]{{\color{#1}{{{#2}}}}}` resolves the issue. But it does not. Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: @AloisPichler no as I tried to explain `#2` is the first token after `\ref[red]` so `i` here. define it as `\newcommand{\rev}[1][blue]{\color{#1}}` then it will work.

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about that. Unfortunately, your code does not close the environment. The mwe is still not correct. Employing `\newcommand{\rev}[1][blue]{\color{#1}}` displays 'black' as red and I am still struggling with the problem.

Comment: @AloisPichler then see my answer which works in both cases... (especially the second variant, which is more robust)

Comment: @Skillmon your code works but I think it's arguably architecturally wrong. The commands should have the same argument structure or have different names.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is the argument "but `beamer` does it, too!" valid?

Comment: @Skillmon I rest my case!